# Why ifelse() works different than if(){}else{} in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Does anyone know why the below code using if(){}else{} structure works:

```r
if(T){
     y = 1
     }else{y = 0}
```

but the below one using ifelse raises an error:

```r
> ifelse(T, y = 1, y = 0)
Error in ifelse(T, y = 1, y = 0) : 
  formal argument "yes" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `ifelse` in this way (instead of the asignment within `ifelse(...)`)

```
y <- ifelse(T,1,0)
```